# JavaScript DOM performance

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a lot of elements in my code which will have to be hidden and displayed dynamically. Hence I will be using a number of `document.getElementById('x').style.display`. I have decided to use different method by creating two functions to do the job for me like this:

```
function displayNone(a){document.getElementById(a).style.display= "none";}
function displaybloack(a){document.getElementById(a).style.display="block";}
```

then I will be just calling these functions with the relevant ID as an argument.

My question: is there any performance hit when using one method over simply using `document.getElementById('x').style.display` directly not through a function call?

Comment: "any performance hit when using one method over the other" --- what is "the other" method?

Comment: "directly not through a function call" --- and how is it different? Just by one function call?

Comment: That has nothing to do with DOM performance. The only difference is a function call, and function calls are cheap (at least compared to DOM operations).

Comment: If you want to try to improve performance, I wouldn't make a function like this. You shouldn't be querying the DOM more than one time for the same id. Assign the element to a variable, and pass the element as a parameter, not the id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question: is there any performance hit when using one method over the other?

Yes. The function call will be slower.

The question is how much. The answer is some incredibly small amount. It is even possible that some engines might in-line the call, making the performance penalty nil. Even if they don't, the performance hit is probably measured in sub-microseconds.

As with any other potential performance concern, the correct approach is to build your app, then find the performance bottlenecks, then fix them.

On a separate topic, as a commenter mentioned, don't refer to DOM elements by their IDs, Instead, refer to them as themselves. Don't pass an ID to a function as you are doing, and find the element from the ID each time the function is called. Instead, pass the DOM element to your function. The cost of doing `getElementById` over and over ago will swamp any cost from an extra function call.

You should also prefer not to set styles directly. Instead, define a class such as

```
.hide { display: none; }
```

and turn your elements on and off by adding or removing that class from the element:

```
function hide(e) { e.classList.add('hide'); }
function show(e) { e.classList.remove('hide'); }
```

Comment: your answer is really helpful and also the additional information that you added. you have stated "_Don't pass an ID to a function as you are doing, and find the element from the ID each time the function is called. Instead, pass the DOM element to your function_" please can you give me code example

Comment: @Tim For an example, see the `hide` and `show` functions I gave. If you want to call them and you only have an ID, then call them as `hide(document.getElementById('foo'))`. However, in most cases, if your code is structured properly you should already have actual element references (instead of IDs) available.

Comment: That is clear thank you. any alternative for The classList property which is not supported in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions?

Comment: @Tim No one uses those anymore, they are obsolete and unsupported. If your job requires you to support them, find a new job. Otherwise, if that element will not have any other classes, just use `e.className = 'hide'` and `e.className = ''`.